# Better type checking help from TS

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have this code:

```
type Foo = {action: 'foo', label: '1'} | {action: 'foo', label: '2'} | {action: 'bar', label: '4'} | {action: "baz", label: "8"}

function action(action: Foo) {
  return action
}

action({action:"baz",label:"")
```

In this case when I've put in `baz` for action I want, and thought, that when I'll put in label the suggestion (autocomplete) will just give me "8" as a suggestion. But it gives me all the labels, 1-8, even though it can't be anything else than 8 if action is `baz`

Why is this? And how can I structure my types to get the expected behavior?

Comment: This is a known bug, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39438

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your `Foo` type.  Are you willing to make `action()` generic like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx5GKW)?  If so I can write up an answer; let me know.

Comment: Thanks! That generics solution in tsplay.dev did exactly what I was looking for. Yes I'm willing to have it as a generic to make it work. 

What do you mean by write up an answer?

Comment: I mean I will compose and then post an answer below.

Comment: Yes, I would really appreciate that!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug; see [microsoft/TypeScript#39438](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39438).  Your `Foo` type is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), and the compiler should have enough information to narrow the type of the function input based on the `action` property, but it does not seem to do so in time to modify the autocompletion suggestions of IntelliSense.  Anyway, this bug is listed as being on the "backlog", which means there are probably no immediate plans to address it.

---

As a workaround, you could make the `action()` function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) like this:

```
function action<T extends Foo["action"]>(action: Extract<Foo, { action: T }>) {
  return action
}
```

I'm making `T`, the generic type parameter, correspond to the `action` property.  The function parameter is typed as `Extract<Foo, {action: T}>` which uses [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to say "only accept the member(s) of `Foo` whose `action` property is `T`".

Let's verify that it behaves as desired.  It still only accepts valid `Foo` values:

```
action({ action: "bar", label: "4" }); // okay
action({ action: "foo", label: Math.random() < 0.5 ? "1" : "2" }); // also okay
action({ action: "baz", label: "4" }) // error!
// -------------------> ~~~~~
// Type '"4"' is not assignable to type '"8"'
```

but now IntelliSense is reasonable and only suggests `label` property values compatible with the `action` property:

[image]

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=46&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKBDAxsAlnAOwC4oByAMwVIBooAbDAIwjpNIEZSoBfKAHzSYc+YmUpwa9JizYAmLrwHpseQm0YYATpIbNWZACwL+glSJIAiDQC8LtXTKgWAHBZ4Aod+QCuBYYSFVAgAeABUoCAAPYAgCABMAZ1gEAG0LM0ILAF0APgAKDNEAUWjNFWD4OFplf1Fw7hyASjR3KChNCGBvTQJAkXduT0K8mqDLDU07KT1LAzduRoBuKAB6Fag4AGsMEHdh0fMncSmHfQBZDGAACwA6Mvi4AFs85uCoAAYbgFYoAH4ndhuSyyeZLVbrDB0BKILY7Pa1EZ9NROGwnaT6CxzHjNNYRTSaOCaACE7lxAFoKZSqdSqTkoAA-RmM0nrULgaCkTEWLi4JIEODATAJBK4ADmBCYdGgwEQoEgZBc3KAA)